# angular.js:14110 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, factory-method

I'm trying to create an array on each diary object and push foods that match the diary id to that array.  Does anyone see anyway I can make this work? Or a reason that it isn't?

```
(Diary Controller)
app.controller("DiaryCtrl", function($scope, $rootScope, $location, DiaryFactory, FoodFactory){

$scope.diaries = [];
$scope.foods = [];


//getMeals
//lists all meals on the diary page
let getAllDiaries = function(){
    DiaryFactory.getDiary($rootScope.user.uid).then(function(FbDiaries) {
        console.log('diaries: ', FbDiaries);
        FoodFactory.getFoodsFB($rootScope.user.uid).then(function(FbFoods){
            console.log('foods from controller', FbFoods);
            FbFoods.forEach(function(food){
                FbDiaries.forEach(function(diary){
                    console.log('foods', food);
                    if(food.mealId === diary.id){
                        diary.foods.push(food);
                        console.log('foods array on diary', diary.foods);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
};
getAllDiaries();
```

[Console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJm1w.png)

Comment: You need to check diary.foods is actually an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check diary.foods is actually an array. If it's OK to modify diary, try

```
diary.foods = diary.foods || [];
diary.foods.push(food);
```